# Get the authorized application list through firewall

Tags: c#, windows-firewall-api

In my application, I broadcast events over the network with standard messages for other application instances, in order to synchronize.

I want to add my app to the authorized list of the firewall, and I do this with:

> NetFwTypeLib API DLL

If I do this in every run, it will be added to the list several times.

My question is: How can I retrieve the list of authorized applications for checking if the application was added before, and then not add it to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want something like this:

```
  Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false); 
  INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType); 
  applications = 
    (INetFwAuthorizedApplications)mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications;
```

For older OS's, look here for complete documentation:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737845%28WS.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For newer OS's (Vista and higher), use [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.